# Node.js connects to MongoDB 5 times

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection

I've been looking for a way to do various operations on a mongo database, depending on which route a user connects to on my website. So doing a html-post to www.mysite.com/data would add info to a mongo DB, and doing a html-get at the same url would get data from the same database. I managed to solve that, but everytime I turn on my server with the website I get 5 connections registred at the mongo database. Why is this, and is it bad?

**My code:**

I'm runing this code in mongo.js:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

module.exports.init = function (callback) {
  var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});
  new mongodb.Db('test', server, {w: 1}).open(function (error, client) {
    //export the client and maybe some collections as a shortcut
    module.exports.client = client;
    module.exports.myCollection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'myCollection');
    callback(error);
  });
};
```

I initialize everything running (app.js):

```
/express set-up/
var mongo = require('./mongo.js');
/.../
mongo.init(function (error) {
    if (error)
        throw error;

    app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode",3000,
            app.settings.env);
    });
});
```

And, for example, the post looks like (still app.js):

```
app.post('/App', function(req, res) {
    users = users.concat(req.body);
    res.redirect('/App');        
//Add user to MongoDB
    mongo.myCollection.insert({name: req.body.name, car: req.body.car, website: req.body.website, phone: req.body.phone}, {safe:true}, function(err, objects) {
    if (err)
        console.warn(err.message);
  });
```

Pretty sure my redirect isn't working as I want it too here, but that's another issue.

Anny suggestions on why I get five connects every time I start the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: >5 open connections for a single db handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593814/mongodb-5-open-connections-for-a-single-db-handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The five connections are because that is the default poolSize (5).  You can adjust it, as outlined in the [server options docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/database.html#server-options) - it also mentions the default.

Comment: Hmm, remembered reading it was some kind of default. Not knowing much about pools, it's allright for it then; that one server creates five connections for it's pool?

Comment: Yes, it's fine you could reduce it if you wished, but if you ever use the server more heavily then more connections will be needed anyway.